# Spark Java - Replace specific String with another String in a dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I'm writing spark application where I have a dataset of 100 fields. I want to replace "Account" with acct in all 100 fields.

`dataset.show();`

```
+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------|
|   id  |    loc| price   |description|postdate           | 
+-------+-------+---------|-----------+-------------------+
|001    |account|315000.25|account    |2020-06-01         |
|account|account|account  |sampledes  |2020-06-05         |
|003    |kochin |315000   |           |account            |
|004    |madurai|null     |abc        |                   |
|005    |account|15000.20 |n.a        |2021/12/01         |
+-------+-------+---------+-----------+-------------------|
```

Result:-  Replace account with acct in all the fields.

```
+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------|
|   id  |    loc| price   |description|postdate           | 
+-------+-------+---------|-----------+-------------------+
|001    |acct   |315000.25|acct       |2020-06-01         |
|acct   |acct   |acct     |sampledes  |2020-06-05         |
|003    |kochin |315000   |           |acct               |
|004    |madurai|null     |abc        |                   |
|005    |acct   |15000.20 |n.a        |2021/12/01         |
+-------+-------+---------+-----------+-------------------|
```

I see the regular expression replace function but we have to write for each column. So I am looking for an alternative.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you cant try this code that iterate over all columns and update the columns with replaced character

```
oldDF.show()
val newDF = oldDF.columns.foldLeft(oldDF) { (replaceDF, colName) =>
  replaceDF.withColumn(
    colName,
    regexp_replace(col(colName), "account", "acct ")
  )
}
newDF.show()
```

Comment: i am using spark java , which i couldn't find  "columns.foldLeft(oldDF) { (replaceDF, colName) => "

Comment: try use "for"  in columns and update your dataframe for example   Dataframe newDF = oldDF
        for (String colName : columns ){
            newDF = newDF.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(col(colName), "account", "acct ")))
        }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But didn't worked as regexp_replace() function not available.

Comment: improt the method  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace